# Is it possible to improve the average precision of YOLO trained on Open Images Dataset by fine-tuning it with COCO?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, pretrained-models, fine-tuning

I consider pre-training a [YOLOv5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) with [Google Open Images Object Detection dataset](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/download.html). The dataset includes general domain categories with ~15 M box samples. After the pre-training is done, I will fine-tune the model on MS COCO dataset.

I would like to do it, if I can improve AP by ~7%. Do you think that it is possible, and I have a logical expectation? Unfortunately, I could not find anywhere anyone has tried an Open Images pre-trained object detector with MSCOCO training.

Comment: To clarify, by MSCOCO, you mean [Microsoft's COCO dataset](https://cocodataset.org/#home), right?

Comment: yes, that was right